SQLAlchemy aggregate table rows into a list in a select sql query?
Is it possible to aggregate table rows to a single list within a sql query in SQLalchemy?
Guess we have Table1, Table2, Table3. We have "id" shared between tables. I know that "id" is the primary key for Table1 and Table2, but a foreign key in Table3. I would like to have a statement like this:
   (select(Table1, Table2, <Aggregate Table3 to list> )
             .join(Table2, onclause=Table2.id == Table1.id, full=True)
             .join(Table3, onclause=Table3.id == Table1.id, full=True)
             .group_by(Table1.id)
             .where(Table1.id==<id-of-interest>))

The result should be a single row containing the columns of Table1, Table2 and a single column with the aggregated list. Any help is appreciated. In the example below, id_1 is the id of interest.
Table1:



Id
table1_col




id_1
table1_col_cont



Table2:



Id
table2_col




id_1
table2_col_cont



Table3:



table3_id
Id
table3_col_a
table3_col_b




1
id_1
table3_col_a_cont1
table3_col_b_cont1


2
id_1
table3_col_a_cont2
table3_col_b_cont2


3
id_2
table3_col_a_cont3
table3_col_b_cont3



Result of select:



Id
table1_col
table2_col
table3_col_agg




id_1
table1_col_cont
table2_col_cont
[{"table3_col_a":"table_col_a_cont1","table3_col_b":"table3_col_b_cont1"},{"table3_col_a":"table_col_a_cont2","table3_col_b":"table3_col_b_cont2"}]




@python_user added some tables.

@python_user let’s say „Id“ is primary key for Table1, foreign primary key for Table2 and foreign key for Table3. I will add an additional column for Table3 for clarification.

{"table3_col_a": "table_col_a_cont1", "table3_col_b": "table3_col_b_cont1"} would be JSON, why do you want it without quotes and using non-curly brackets?

@MatBailie you are right, will correct it in the example.

Yes, however in sqlalchemy query language. I can’t find the json_agg function in the documentation.

Got the expected/desired result for the sample input provided. Here it is  per the requirement mentioned in the question,
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, func, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, declarative_base
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    table1_col = Column(String)


class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    table2_col = Column(String)


class Table3(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table3'
    table3_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id = Column(String, ForeignKey('table1.id'))
    table3_col_a = Column(String)
    table3_col_b = Column(String)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session.add_all([
    Table1(id='id_1', table1_col='table1_col_cont'),
    Table2(id='id_1', table2_col='table2_col_cont'),
    Table3(id='id_1', table3_id=1, table3_col_a='table3_col_a_cont1', table3_col_b='table3_col_b_cont1'),
    Table3(id='id_1', table3_id=2, table3_col_a='table3_col_a_cont2', table3_col_b='table3_col_b_cont2'),
    Table1(id='id_2', table1_col='table1_col_cont2'),
    Table2(id='id_2', table2_col='table2_col_cont2'),
    Table3(id='id_2', table3_id=3, table3_col_a='table3_col_a_cont3', table3_col_b='table3_col_b_cont3')
])

session.commit()

table1_df = pd.read_sql(select(Table1), engine)
table2_df = pd.read_sql(select(Table2), engine)
table3_df = pd.read_sql(select(Table3), engine)

print("Table1 DataFrame:")
print(table1_df)
print("\nTable2 DataFrame:")
print(table2_df)
print("\nTable3 DataFrame:")
print(table3_df)

id_of_interest = 'id_1'

stmt = (
    select(
        Table1.id,
        Table1.table1_col,
        Table2.table2_col,
        func.json_group_array(
            func.json_object(
                'table3_col_a', Table3.table3_col_a,
                'table3_col_b', Table3.table3_col_b
            )
        ).label('table3_col_agg')
    )
    .join(Table2, Table2.id == Table1.id)
    .join(Table3, Table3.id == Table1.id)
    .group_by(Table1.id, Table1.table1_col, Table2.table2_col)
    .where(Table1.id == id_of_interest)
)

result = session.execute(stmt).fetchone()

df = pd.DataFrame([{
    "Id": result[0],
    "table1_col": result[1],
    "table2_col": result[2],
    "table3_col_agg": result[3]
}])
print(df)

session.close()



Found a solution with json_agg, will add it to my question. Still thank you.
